# Pre-flight Api error using Angular service?

Tags: angular, http-post, angular2-services

I have to send authorization token in header with post call to get data from server it throws below error. What is correct approach to send attribute in header to render response ?

#### search.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getSearch(searchObj: {}) {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic bTA5NDRpb25idXMuYXTVNAMjAxNw==',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            },
            data: searchObj
        };
        console.log("searchObj", searchObj)
        return this.http.post('http://service/getHistoricEvents', JSON.stringify(config))
            //.map(res => res.json());
            .map(res => console.log(res));
    }

}
```

ERROR

```
Failed to load http://service/getHistoricEvents: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
core.js:1350 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
```

Comment: If api is not handling CORS preflight properly then you probably need to use a proxy on server you control or third party service to access that api. If you control the api, you need to implement CORS properly

Comment: one of the backend dev controlled the api so we need to add CORS to api so it can handle preflight request.

Comment: yo're using HttpClient, so use HttpHeaders, see documentation https://angular.io/guide/http#headers . About your question, I'll use a interceptor https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses

Comment: @Eliseo Can you please give me example code i am trying it but still throws error , i will appreciate help here

Comment: here is what i implemented `return this.http
          .post('http://service/getHistoricEvents', searchObj, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set(   'Authorization','Basic bTA5NDg1QGNvbR0LmNvbTpjYnVzTVNAMjAxNw==')
          })`